# Microsoft Graph Api - updating PasswordProfile not working when null

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have a b2c environment setup and linked to an application which allows users to sign up.

One of the processes I want to run on a schedule is to update the PasswordProfile of users so that in certain situations I can force users to change their password on their next sign in attempt.

As documented (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#permissions), I have added and consented to the `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` (Delegated) permission for the application accessing Microsoft Graph.

Request:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}
{
  "passwordProfile": {
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true
  }
}
```

When I run this either in C# code or through Postman, it returns the following error message:

```
"error": {
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
    ...
```

However I have been able to run the same request through https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer, where I have been able to update the PasswordProfile of a user.

The strange thing, is if I then return to the C# code or Postman, and run the same operation against the **SAME** user that I updated in Graph Explorer, it now works.

Therefore it appears that I have the correct permissions set, but I can only update PasswordProfile if it is not already null. However, when the user is created when signing up through the B2C screens, the PasswordProfile is set to null at this point.

Has anyone come across this before? Or able to reproduce this?

Comment: Please share the details of how you have acquired the access token in C# and Postman and also expose the error details including request id and timestamp. What I think is that the permission is not added in the token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to add the application as a 'Global Administrator' as detailed in the accepted answer here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/9024/error-while-updating-the-password-profile.html

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue when I was trying to [update the passwordProfile of a user to reset their password](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-3-update-the-passwordprofile-of-a-user-to-reset-their-password)

In line with [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http),

> In delegated access, the calling app must be assigned the
> Directory.AccessAsUser.All delegated permission on behalf of the
> signed-in user. In application-only access, the calling app must be
> assigned the User.ReadWrite. All application permission **and at least
> the User Administrator Azure AD role**.

[image: Screenshot]

Once I added the User Administrator role to my Enterprise app/App registration, it worked ok